# Как сделать, чтобы вертикальный список выпадал при нажатии а не наведении

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы вертикальный список выпадал при нажатии а не наведении, чтобы получилось, как на фото.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo0KI.png]

Comment: а есть ссылки какие-нибудь с примерами ?

Comment: можно без js сделать

Comment: как если не  секрет ? всё что я нахожу это срабатывание при наведении и после того как курсор отводят оно пропадает а я ищу чтобы активировалось при нажатии и не закрывалось после отвода курсора

Answer (score 4):

**Самый примитивный вариант:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.list {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.list__item__checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.sublist {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
}

.list__item__checkbox:checked~.sublist {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
    <label class="list__item__label" for="one">one</label>
    <input class="list__item__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="one">

    <ul class="sublist">
      <li class="sublist__item">item 1</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 2</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="list__item">
    <label class="list__item__label" for="two">two</label>
    <input class="list__item__checkbox" type="checkbox" id="two">

    <ul class="sublist">
      <li class="sublist__item">item 1</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 2</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**C помощью [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within):**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.toggle {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sublist {
  display: none;
}

.list__item:focus-within > .sublist {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list__item">
   <button class="toggle">one</button>
    <ul class="sublist">
      <li class="sublist__item">item 1</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 2</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="list__item">
    <button class="toggle">two</button>
    <ul class="sublist">
      <li class="sublist__item">item 1</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 2</li>
      <li class="sublist__item">item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 4):

Бывает удобно разместить радио-кнопки внутри label, чтобы постоянно не возиться с id-for.

`.bubu:checked ~ .radio { background-color: orange; }` (перевод на русский): Когда радио-кнопка с классом 'bubu' отмечена, где-то ниже в коде найти элемент с классом 'radio' и покрасить его в оранжевый. Туда уже сверху можно добавить любые другие стили.

```css
.mama { list-style: none; }

.bubu, .ul { display: none; }

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover .name {
  color: red;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.bubu:checked ~ .radio {
  background-color: orange;
}

.bubu:checked ~ .ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul class="mama">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="bubu" type="radio" name="bubu"><!-- Скрытый -->
      <span class="radio"></span><!-- Фейковая радио-кнопка со своими стилями -->
      
      <span class="name">Тест - 1</span>
      <ul class="ul">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </label>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="bubu" type="radio" name="bubu">
      <span class="radio"></span>
      
      <span class="name">Тест - 2</span>
      <ul class="ul">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </label>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <label>
      <input class="bubu" type="radio" name="bubu">
      <span class="radio"></span>
      
      <span class="name">Тест - 3</span>
      <ul class="ul">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо большое